# I can't move, rotate, scale GameObject in Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't move, rotate or scale Objects. Why is this?

Note: I am using *Unity 4*.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

From the Screenshot you posted, you are clearly in **Pan Mod**:

[image]

You need to be in *Move Mode* to move Objects, *Rotate Mode* to rotate objects, *Scale Mode* to scale Objects and *RectTransform Mode* to modify Canvas and UI Object RectTransform.

**Move Mode**:

[image]

**Rotate Mode**:

[image]

**Scale Mode**:

[image]

**RectTransform Scale Mode**:

[image]

---

I also noticed that you only have the *Game View*. You should have both Game and Scene views. You need to be in the *Scene View* in order to move,rotate or scale an Object.

Reset your layout then you will have Scene View. You can use the image below to see how to do that.

[image]

You can find more about this [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html).

Comment: Nice. You don't have enough reputation to up vote my answer but you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) my answer by clicking on the check icon stead of the arrow up icon.

Answer (score 9):

I came here from a similar, but different problem. Every time I clicked a tool, it would jump back to the the Pan tool. Couldn't even select the other tools and there were no tool widgets in the viewport.

Turns out it was because I was using ProBuilder add-on and had left it in edge mode rather than object mode. Switching back to object mode solved it immediately.

Just in case someone else comes here from the same frustration as me.

Comment: This is exactly my problem, so easy to overlook.

Comment: Thanks. Can you describe how to disable the ProBuilder add-on?

Comment: If you want to completely disable probuilder, just find it in the package manager and uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac, caps lock would prevent most drag features, including this.

Answer (score 0):

Either press <kbd>G</kbd>, or click the 3D cube icon circled in the screenshot below:

[image]

I find that Unity always cancels the selection. I don't know why, but this always works for me.