# Unity scene view bug with panning and rotating

Tags: unity-game-engine

I cant rotate the camera with the RMB, no panning with middle mouse button and the arrows on an object don't move the object, only the inner circle

thanks in advance

ned

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530651/i-cant-move-rotate-scale-gameobject-in-unity-editor/43533323#43533323) post. Probably the-same problem and solution

Comment: it is a bug, I already know about that stuff, but thanks

Comment: The bug affects all my projects, is there a way to set settings back to factory settings

Comment: If it's a bug, why would factory reset fix it? I don't think it is a bug but you beleive so then file for a bug report. Help-->Report a Bug...

Comment: true that, ill put in a bug report

Comment: any other ideas>

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: It would be good if you add animated gif of what's going. You can use LICEcap to record it. I will see if that's a work-around.

Comment: https://giphy.com/gifs/3ohzdOPDlt1IrMGZpK

Comment: I wasn't notified after your last comment. What's your Unity and OS version?

Comment: All I had to do was restart my computer